# How to set Visibility for a button from another activity by using ad listener in android

Tags: bundle

I'm developing an android application in which I'm trying to set visiblity for button by ad listener. There are two activities

1) MainActivity-which contains 2 buttons button1 & button3, WebView and interstitial Ad.
another activity is AdActivity on which I have a invisible button. I want to make that button visible by ad listener from interstitial ad.

```
        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mAdview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);



        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(interstitialAd.isLoaded())
                {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }

                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()
                                     {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onAdClicked() {

                                             Intent nextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdActivity.class);
                                             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                             bundle.putInt("VAL", 1);

                                             nextActivity.putExtras(bundle);
                                             startActivity(nextActivity);
                                         }
                                     }


        ); 

    }
}
```

```
 Bundle bun=getIntent().getExtras();
        int val=bun.getInt("VAL");


        if(val==1)
        {
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass value in `Bundle`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("VAL", 1 + "");
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get value from `Bundle`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String strVal = extras.getString("VAL");
int intVal = Integer.parseInt(strVal);
```

Comment: " Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras()"  
Whenever I wrote this line on 2nd activity the app crashes on clicking on the interstitial ad